# List Box multiple value selection

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created form based on query output. I had used three comboboxes and one list box. First combobox gives me list of Dept, selection of Dept on second gives me location of that Dept (distinct), the third gives me (distinct) project from that location, then next is list box who displays the some codes of that project. The problem is I am able to select only one code from that list and get output in Excel.

If I wanted to select two values at a time, how would I do that?

If I select `Multi Select` from list box property than I am able to select multiple values but I am not getting output.

Comment: Is your output to Excel firing when you select a line in the listbox, if so then you may need to move this to an export button etc. You would need to loop through the listbox lines and check those which are selected and then write those to your Excel file.

Answer (score 8):

When a List Box has its `Multi Select` property set to "None" then you can retrieve the selected value by simply referring to

```
Me.List0.Value
```

However, for multi-select List Box controls you need to iterate through the `ItemsSelected` collection to determine the items that are selected:

```
Dim ItemIndex As Variant
For Each ItemIndex In Me.List0.ItemsSelected
    MsgBox Me.List0.ItemData(ItemIndex)
Next
```

Comment: Is it possible to have hidden columns - so using the hidden column to hold a "Code" and only showing the read friendly list?