# Dynamic Display of Columns In a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

A complicated Problem but I will try to explain.
I have a main worksheet "OPL" with several columns into it. I have written a code in VBA which extracts the Information based on my given criteria and Displays all the columns with the extracted Information in a new worksheet "QB".

Now lets say "OPL" has 10 columns from `A to J` and my code extracts the specific rows and Displays it on "QB" under the respective column headings.

Now I want that the user should select the columns he want to see on "QB". Lets say he wants to see the Information only for column C and D . So he selects column C and D from the Dropdown list and when he runs the macro, He should get only columns C and column D on "QB".

p.s. I know it is too broad a question and also I cannot post the code as it will make things more complicated. I am not asking for the code but can anyone guide me how to Display columns dynamically ?

Comment: Add in a listbox for the user to select the relevant fields, then either exclude the other fields from the analysis or have the columns hidden on QB. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17090864/6028892

Comment: CELLS should help in your copying, so for column d, cells(row,"D") where "D" is from your combo, if your combo is "C and D", you'll need to SPLIT by "and" and use the returned array.

Comment: @Will thanks for the quick reply. But I would like to clear some Points.  a) I cannot exclude other fields from Analysis as one user requires to see the values of Column C and D, but may be other user Needs all the columns or maybe 5.  b) It shoukd be dynamic. e.g. If I select column A and C from the list, Only column A and C should appear on "QB", so I guess hiding the columns will also not help as everytime I would Need to hide the unwanted column manually.

Comment: This could be done with a floating userform window, hovering above QB, with the listbox inside. Whenever a change is registered on the listbox selection (different columns selection) the subroutine changes which columns are visible on QB.

Comment: Would you consider a **macro based** approach ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, I think so that would be the best Approach as I am already using a macro to extract data from "OPL" and displaying it in "QB".

Answer (score 0):

Say *QPL* is like:

[image]

Enter this *Event Macro* in the *QB* worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim crit As Range, fCol As String
    Dim lCol As String, fRow As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, K1 As Long, K2 As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, Nul As String

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set crit = Range("A1:D1")
    Nul = ""
    If Intersect(crit, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If wf.CountIf(crit, Nul) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        fCol = [A1]
        lCol = [B1]
        fRow = [C1]
        lRow = [D1]
        K1 = 2
        K2 = 1
        For i = fRow To lRow
            For j = L2Num(fCol) To L2Num(lCol)
                Cells(K1, K2).Formula = "=QPL!" & Num2L(j) & i
                K2 = K2 + 1
            Next j
            K2 = 1
            K1 = K1 + 1
        Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Function L2Num(S As String) As Long
    L2Num = Asc(S) - 64
End Function

Public Function Num2L(L As Long) As String
    Num2L = Chr(64 + L)
End Function
```

In *QB* we enter the first desired column in **A1**, the last desired column in **B1**, the first desired row in **C1**, and the last desired row in **D1**

When this little criteria block has been filled, the macro will run and populate cells to retrieve the desired data:

[image]

Just change any of the four cells in the little criteria block to re-run the macro.